# Java: update CRC32 from a stream

Tags: java, crc32

Am I misunderstanding the use of either of the `CRC32` or `CheckedInputStream` classes to calculate a checksum by continuously updating with the latest input?  When the input is <= 128KiB a valid CRC32 is generated. Anything larger than 128KiB and the checksum fails. Below is some code I am working with (using a `CRC32` object and `BufferedInputStream` but the same problem happens if I use a `CheckedInputStream` to keep track of the CRC32).

I would appreciate any advice or comments, thank you

```
private static long calcCRC32() throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
    int BLOCK_SIZE = 128*1024; //128KiB
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

    CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
    crc32.reset();

    while((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE)) > 0){         
        crc32.update(buffer, 0, len);
        buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
    }

    return crc32.getValue();
}
```

Comment: +1 for trimming down the text and the example code considerably. Keep up this way of thinking.

Comment: Is calling `crc32.reset` really necessary ?